# Bavarian German pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation, resource, bavarian

I've been studying German for over a year now. I think I could pass a B2 exam.

However, being in München, I would like to improve my understanding of the Bavarian dialect, mostly listening comprehension.

What really helped my Hochdeutsch listening skills, is that I inserted the IPA symbols from Wiktionary for a lot of words into my flashcard app [Anki](https://apps.ankiweb.net/) and drilled those. This as helped me a lot, much much more than just trying to listen and get used to the sounds.

I would like to do the same with Bavarian. I am listening occasionally to the show "Dahoam is Dahoam", but ideally I would like to have a online dictionary which has the IPA pronunciation and meanings for words in the Bavarian dialect, which I can insert into Anki and drill.

Also I am looking for any materials that discuss the Bavarian pronunciation, some patterns of how things change compared to Hochdeutsch etc. It can also be written in German, for example someones master or doctoral thesis on the dialect etc.

I did find this dictionary, which does have some kind of a Lautschrift for words. Can anybody tell me to what IPA symbols the symbols he explains here correspond to?
https://www.bayrisches-woerterbuch.de/bairisch-lernen/aussprache-bayrisch/

Any other pronunciation articles, materials, TV-shows, dictionaries for the Bavarian dialect are really welcome!

Comment: Did you already see https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bairische_Dialekte#Phonologie ?

Comment: I hadn't read that, it's useful.
In the Bairisches Wörterbuch, I gather that in IPA a and à are [a], å is [ɒ], e is [e], ä is [ɛ], o is [o]. Then I can basically use this dictionary to learn all the words/pronunciations there using Anki. Probably there aren't any better Bavarian dictionaries.
I guess this is good enough, I'll study the dictionary and watch a lot of "Dahoam is Dahoam" and I think I should learn to understand Bairisch pretty well.

Comment: Oh I found here 5 interesting rules: https://www.quelle.de/mode-freizeit/alpenwelt/rund-um-die-tracht/bayerisch-fuer-aenfaenger/#els=true&sview=extern

Comment: Should we assume that everybody knows what "Anki" is?

Comment: Pronounciation changes all over, it varies from region to region. So you can't learn the one and only Bavarian, just some more or less general rules, but there are many many deviations if you look at details.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to recommend the [REDE Regionalsprachen Project](https://www.regionalsprache.de/home.aspx) to you. You can find a comprehensive collection of material there including lots of maps about the Bavarian dialect and their distribution with detailed analysis. It's not easy to explore that site but try to follow all those sublinks listed there.